# Establishing the inequality $\cos \alpha \sin \alpha < \alpha < \frac{\sin \alpha}{\cos \alpha}$ via a geometric argument

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

[image]

Hi guys. Could you please hint me toward how I could start a proof on this type of question? I have information on the area of $\triangle{OQP}$ and $\triangle{QPR}$.

I have that $Area_{\triangle{OQP}} = \frac{1}{2} (OP)^2 cos(\alpha) sin(\alpha)$ and $Area_{\triangle{QPR}} = \frac{1}{2} sin(\alpha) (OP) (QR)$.

Any hints on how I could take it from here would be sincerely appreciated.

Kindest regards

Answer (score 1):

The "two triangles" in the statement refers to the triangles $\triangle OQP$ and $\triangle OPR$.

Geometrically, the following inequalities are clear: the area of $\triangle OQP$ is smaller than the area of the circular sector, which is again smaller than the area of $\triangle OPR$.

Knowing that $OP = 1$, the area of the circular sector is just the angle $\alpha$, more or less by the definition of radian.

What inequalities do you get from that?

Comment: Thank you very much for this.

Answer (score 1):

remember that $OP = r = 1$ so you have already established

$$Area_{\triangle{OQP}} = \frac{1}{2}\cos \alpha \sin \alpha $$ $$Area_{\triangle{QPR}} = \frac{1}{2} QR \cdot sin \alpha $$

Now, you can notice that the two triangles are similar because $PR$ is tangent to the circle,  so $QR = \frac{PQ^2}{OQ} = \frac{\sin^2{\alpha}}{\cos{\alpha}}$, and that the area of the sector is $\frac12\alpha $ (why?).

Lastly, you can easily see that the triangle inside the sector is less than the sector itself which is less than the sum of the  triangles, therefore

$$\cos \alpha  \sin \alpha < \alpha < \cos \alpha \sin \alpha +\frac{ \sin^3(\alpha)}{\cos \alpha}=\frac{\sin \alpha \cdot (\sin^2 \alpha + \cos^2 \alpha)}{\cos \alpha} = \frac{\sin \alpha }{\cos\alpha }$$